# Downloading every package with Tex live

Tags: texlive

How can I download every package with Tex Live? I remember finding some command with `tlmgr`, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it was, or which answer I was reading, and to what question.

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific: as standard, TeX Live installs 'everything'.

Comment: For instance, after having downloaded TeXmaker, I now want to be able to use `\usepackage{foo}` for any `foo`. Currently I cannot do this, I think.

Comment: That is, any foo that I find online. The example that came to mind was wasysym, but I remember that last time I installed I found a way to install a lot of packages that included wasysym.

Comment: Texmaker is a front end, it's not TeX Live: did you install it?

Comment: I just installed Texmaker. I think I must be terribly confused, although I could have sworn this is how I went about it before.

Comment: Well, that did what I wanted. I have no idea what I was thinking... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html) you have a complete documentation regarding the `tlmgr` command line. As far as I have glanced through it, there is only an option to *update* all packages using the following command: `tlmgr update --self --all`.

As for installing, you only have the option to install *one* package at a time (with all it's dependencies) using `tlmgr install package_to_install`.

Given this, the easiest way to install *everything* is (probably) to perform a reinstall of Tex Live. As @Joseph pointed out, Tex Live install everything by default.

Comment: Note that `tlmgr` *doesn't* follow dependencies.

Comment: @egreg: The provided documentation regarding the `install` command states `By default this also installs all packages on which the given pkgs are dependent`. Same goes for the `update` command.

Answer (score 16):

If you haven't installed it, call `tlmgr install scheme-full` and it will pull in each and everything.